# Gradle version 1.8 is required. Current version is 1.9-rc-3 - Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Gradle updates and error now, I can't import my project.

Error log:

```
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-rc-3-bin.zip'.
Build file '/home/luiz/Dropbox/projetos/droido-beta/droido.torpedos/build.gradle' line: 9
A problem occurred evaluating project ':droido.torpedos'.
A problem occurred evaluating project ':droido.torpedos'.
Gradle version 1.8 is required. Current version is 1.9-rc-3. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/luiz/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-1.8-all.zip
```

How solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this issue with android studio 0.4.2, I changed the android tools in build.gradle from 0.6+ to 0.7+

original line in build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
```

Changed to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
```

Then I just ran Tools->Android->Sync Project with Gradle Files and everything worked.

Answer (score 6):

Gradle 1.9 is not yet supported by the build tools.

Consider using Gradle Wrapper which will download it's own version of gradle that your project is built from.

See (http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)

Add the wrapper task and set it to 1.8
then run `gradle wrapper`

You might have to re-import your project to AS and when you do, tell it to use the wrapper.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Any example of how to configure this on Android Studio?

Comment: I added the wrapper line as shown in the link, it didn't work. A how to is needed, else the answer is virtually useless.

Comment: This answer is a bit outdated. If you are using 0.4+ of Android Studio then you need 1.9 Gradle. no other version currently works.

Comment: @MichaelBarany  Really?  I am on Android Studio 0.4.2, and it still tells me to use gradle 1.8...

Comment: See http://tools.android.com/recent for details, but it looks like they fixed the error message in 0.4.1 for Gradle versioning. `Gradle 1.10 has been released, but Android Gradle plugin 0.7.3 (which Studio 0.4.1 is using) does not work properly with Gradle 1.10, and the error message was very confusing (because the plugin crashes before it gets to the version check). In 0.4.1 we detect the mismatched version earlier and give a sensible message. We are working on an updated Android Gradle plugin which (among other feature work) will work with Gradle 1.10.`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem using Ubuntu (Linux Mint) this week and I couldn't get the wrapper working. My final solution was to:

1. Download and unzip Gradle 1.8 from http://www.gradle.org/downloads
2. Remove the .gradle directory from your user directory (/home//.gradle) (I'm not sure if this is actually necessary)
3. Re-import the project to Android Studio, and in the import options, specify "local gradle distribution" - point to the newly installed/unzipped Gradle 1.8

And fingers crossed your error disappears.

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove directory $USER_HOME.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.9-rc-3-bin using command. In Windows:

> cd .gradle\wrapper\dists
>
> rmdir /s gradle-1.9-rc-3-bin

Comment: This doesn't help - it will be downloaded again.